# Why doesn't my call to on() (or live()) work with elements added using append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an issue preventing a hyperlink from being clicked using `on()`.  I've researched on Stackoverflow but have yet to find an answer.

The code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.spoiler > a', function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then, later, a link gets added like this:

```
$("#chatContainer").append("<div class='spoiler'><a href='blah'>lorem ipsum</a></div>");
```

But when I click on the link, the link is still followed.  I've confirmed that it's because the `click` handler isn't being called at all.  I've also confirmed that the `$(document).ready()` function **is** being called, and that `$('.spoiler > a')` correctly selects the `<a>` element after it's been added.

So, **Why isn't it working!?**  Isn't `on()` supposed to bind to all elements that match its selector, even ones added later?

---

**[Edit]**  If I put the code in the `onclick` of the `<a>` element, it works:

```
$("#chatContainer").append("<div class='spoiler'><a href='blah' onclick='return doNothingWhenClicked();'>lorem ipsum</a></div>");

...

function doNothingWhenClicked()
{
    return false;
}
```

So why doesn't it work when using `on()`!?

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/zwLzz/

Comment: In what version of jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do'h!  I found it - it was in code I hadn't posted, sorry.

Elsewhere, I had a `click` handler set for the `.spoiler` div, which removed the `.spoiler` class.

```
$('.spoiler').on('click', function(e)
{
    $(this).removeClass('.spoiler');
});
```

Since the parent's `click` handler is called before the child's, when I clicked on the link, the `.spoiler` class was being removed from the parent... which simultaneously removed the `click` binding from the child!

---

Normally I'd delete this question, but since I consider this a pretty tricky bug, I'll leave this question/answer here, in case it helps someone else in the future.

Also, I'm open to suggestions about how best to handle this situation...